# AndroidScript button handling

Tags: javascript, android

I would like to have an array of buttons and one handler for them all.
It's pretty easy to define the array, but how to get the handler the info which button was actually pressed?

```
for (var i=0; i<=7; i++)
{
   Butt[i] = app.CreateButton( i, 1/8, 1/8 );
   Butt[i].SetOnTouch( ButHand );
   lay.AddChild( Butt[i] );
}
app.AddLayout( lay );

function ButHand( )
{
  app.Alert( "Button pressed, but which one?" );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want it Lord Of The Rings style eh? One handler to rule them all!

Well you are in luck, if you check out the "Calculator" sample demo, it gives you a good idea how to handle many buttons with one handler using the app.GetLastButton() function:-

```
function btns_OnTouch()
{
    app.Vibrate( "0,100" );

    //Get button text.
    btn = app.GetLastButton();
    var txt = btn.GetText();
    :
    :
```

}

Note: There is also a GetLastImage function ;)